# Roundcube — кто может помочь с сессиями?

Tags: php, сессия, roundcube

Привет!
Есть Roundecube который работает нормально пока работает отдельно от проекта.

Но как только мы подключаем его к проекту, выдает ошибку

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function kill() on a non-object in usr/share/roundcubemail/program/include/rcmail.php on line 735
```

На нашем сайте пользователь проходит авторизацию, если все ОК открывается страница с авторизацией Roundcube где после ввода логина и пароля от почты, открывается белая страница и вы дает ошибку что выше в логах.

Проблема в том что мы кидаем данные в сессии, а в файле **index.php (roundecube)** мы должны делать проверку, если есть данные в сессии загружаем  страницу дальше если нет то делаем редирект.

Так вот ошибка вылетает если в файле вставляем код

```
session_start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению не приведен код, на котором падает roundcube, и не указана версия roundcube.

Насколько понимаю, падение происходит на строке `$this->session->kill();`
Как следует из текста ошибки объект `$this->session` в момент выполнения команды не существует.

Вызывая свой собственный `session_start()`, вы создаете новую сессию и тем самым блокируете попытку roundcube создать сессию самому, что и приводит к аварийному завершению работы. Наверняка, у вас в логах имеются предупреждения о неудачных попытках повторного создания сессии.

Если вы хотите встраиваться в стороннюю программу, то весьма желательно использовать механизмы этой программы. В частности, можно попытаться использовать сессию, созданную самим roundcube.